# Qt C++ MySQL to QTableView Multiple Connections Tables Empty

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qtableview

I'm trying to view data from MySQL database to two TableViews in qt C++ application and now I'm always getting an empty tables but with the correct header names in database and the row counts, but inside the tables there's no data, it's just empty.

I don't know if I'm fetching the data right or not?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "test_db");

    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("abc123");
    db.setDatabaseName("test_db");

    if(db.open())
    {
        qDebug("Connected!");

        QSqlQuery query(db);

        if(!query.exec("SELECT * FROM employees"))
        {
            qDebug(query.lastError().text().toLatin1());
        }
        else
        {
            QSqlQueryModel* model = new QSqlQueryModel();

            model->setQuery(query);

            ui->tableView->setModel(model);

            ui->tableView->show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug("Connection Failed!");
    }

    db.close();
}

{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("test_db");

    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("abc123");
    db.setDatabaseName("test_db");

    if(db.open())
    {
        qDebug("Connected!");

        QSqlQuery query(db);

        if(!query.exec("SELECT * FROM clients"))
        {
            qDebug(query.lastError().text().toLatin1());
        }
        else
        {
            QSqlQueryModel* model = new QSqlQueryModel();

            model->setQuery(query);

            ui->tableView_2->setModel(model);

            ui->tableView_2->show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug("Connection Failed!");
    }

    db.close();

    db = QSqlDatabase();

    db.removeDatabase("test_db");
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to add the database twice. From the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase): *If there already exists a database connection called connectionName, that connection is removed.*
Replace the second call to `addDatabase` with [`database`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#database)

Comment: Thanks for Relpying, I did what you said but the result is aslo empty tableviews.

Comment: I'd suggest working through the [examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-sql.html). Probably start with the [book](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-books-example.html) one

Comment: When i erase the second connection the data in tableview 1 appear!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (db.open())
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("SELECT * FROM librarian");
    if(query.exec()){
        QSqlQueryModel* model = new QSqlQueryModel();
        model -> setQuery(query);
        ui -> tableView -> setModel(model);
    }

}
else {
    qDebug() << "Not Loaded";

}
```